# Motion layout(alpha4) issue with recyclerview onswipe item

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I am using alpha4 `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'` of constraint layout. First I created a single layout and do onswipe animation it is working perfectly with motion layout then I patched the layout with a recyclerview. **Now problem comes into picture**
Issue:

1. If I am doing onswipe in a particular item of rv then it's getting lagged.
2. Suppose I am doing swipe on the 1st item of the rv now after full swipe you will find that same swiped has already happen with 13th no item, 25th no item and so on. So after every 12 item same swipe you can check while you are scrolling.

I have posted the whole project in [Github](https://github.com/pom1004/MotionLayoutWithRecyclerview) and also created a sample [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ldoN4YcveH3zLi9q4Wn4LqBK4S44iUBf).

_For quick gist of motion layout here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_btn"
    app:showPaths="true"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/iv_recorded_program"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rl_recorded_program_info"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/styleRecordedProgramImage"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/guide_list_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/guide_list_height"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/rl_recorded_program_info"
        layout="@layout/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/guide_list_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_recorded_program"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/guide_list_height"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

*And here is the layout description*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:duration="1000">
        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragRight"
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/rl_recorded_program_info"
            app:touchAnchorSide="right"/>
    </Transition>


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/iv_recorded_program"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/guide_list_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/guide_list_height"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rl_recorded_program_info"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/rl_recorded_program_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/guide_list_height"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_recorded_program"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/guide_list_height"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/iv_recorded_program"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/guide_list_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/guide_list_height"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/rl_recorded_program_info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/guide_list_height"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iv_recorded_program"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/guide_list_height"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_recorded_program"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Comment: Also posted the question to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples/issues/77

Answer (score -3):

Finally the issue is fixed by one of colleague. @Srini Thanks for the solution.

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }
```

Just need to override this method in adapter of recyclerview.

*[Note:]Still the lag is there while swiping.*